# SQL TIMESTAMP strftime

Tags: sql, sqlite

как из `strftime('%s', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` обратно в нормальный обычный формат

Comment: Какая БД? Если SQLLite - попробуйте SELECT datetime(1092941466, 'unixepoch')

Comment: Спасибо помогло

Answer (score 0):

Используйте Datetime:

```
SELECT datetime(1092941466, 'unixepoch')
```